# Package xkeyval Error when using menukeys and csquotes

Tags: errors, csquotes, xkeyval, menukeys

I have the following minimum “working” example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{menukeys} % switch with csquotes to fix
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\title{Test}
\author{Nomen nescio}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \enquote{Hello World}

    \keys{\enterwin}
\end{document}
```

When I `pdflatex` the file I get the error `Package xkeyval Error: no value specified for key german`. If you remove `german=guillemets`, everything works fine but I don't get the desired output.

The solution is to switch the usepackages for `menukeys` and `csquotes`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\title{Test}
\author{Nomen nescio}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \enquote{Hello World}

    \keys{\enterwin}
\end{document}
```

My question is simple: What exactly is the error and why is switching the usepackages a solution?

Comment: As a German I should say that the `guillemets` are rather unusual ;-) And switching the load order is sometimes necessary since some packages do redefinitions or provide definitions other packages rely on

Comment: As a German I agree. The original code was `german=quotes`, but I changed it to `guillemets` to have a clearer distinction between the output with or without the option in my minimum working example. I am asking to avoid similar errors with the same reason in the future. Thanks for the general advice though.

Comment: Unfortunately, `menukeys` loads `catoptions`, which breaks the key setting for `csquotes`

Comment: @egreg: it would a good idea to avoid this package -- it breaks so often things by trying to be to clever.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I fully agree

Comment: Someone should tell it @Tobi.